# Why getting Grpc.Core.RpcException StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Connect Failed", with Google Cloud Firestore 1.0.0-beta05 C# SetAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are using C# with the Google.Cloud.Firestore.1.0.0-beta05 NuGet package, and we always get a Grpc.Core.RpcException when we try to call SetAsync.

Details:

1. Visual Studio 2017
2. .NET Framework V4.6.2
3. ASP.NET
4. Version: Google.Cloud.Firestore.1.0.0-beta05
5. Date Published: Thursday, June 07, 2018 (6/7/2018)
6. Environment Variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** has been set.
7. Proxy configured in web.config per our Company setup.
8. Environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy have been set.

Can anyone help us understand why we get the following?

**Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Connect Failed")**

The relevant snippets follow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Eamonn

**C# Method:**

```
private async Task FirebaseSetAsync(string projectId)
{
    var database = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId: projectId);

    var docRef = database.Collection("users").Document("company");

    Dictionary<string, object> user = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "First", "Alan" },
        { "Middle", "Mathison" },
        { "Last", "Turing" },
        { "Born", 1912 }
    };

    try
    {
        var result = await docRef.SetAsync(user);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Error("Exception.", exception);
    }
}
```

**web.config snippet:**

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://w.x.y.z:pppp/" />  
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

**Log file snippet:**

```
20:15:26.938 [   7] [(null)] ERROR FirebaseFive.Controllers.HomeController - Exception.
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Connect Failed")
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.WriteBatch.<CommitAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference.<SetAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FirebaseFive.Controllers.HomeController.<FirebaseSetAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in
```

D:\Projects\Git\Firebase\FirebaseFive\FirebaseFive\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 33

Answer (score 2):

With grateful assistance from some people at Google, the answer is as follows:

The Firestore library/SDK communicates using the **HTTP/2.0** Protocol and our Company Proxy (squid-cache) **does not** support HTTP/2.0.

Now we have to see if we can get a list of IP Addresses for the Firestore and associated services/domains so that we can bypass the Proxy for those Addresses.